# SquirrelSQL keyboard shortcuts on MacOS

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I am running SquirrelSQL on MacOS.

Many keyboard shortcuts do not work.

For example: `find` is supposed to be mapped to `CTRL-F`, but neither `CTRL-F` nor `CMD-F` work.  Similarly, `replace` (supposed to be `CTRL-H`).

Please advise.